# How often did the European Parliament use its optional secret ballot rule?

Tags: european-union, voting, european-parliament, secret-ballot

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_methods_in_deliberative_assemblies):

> If at least 20% of the Parliament requests it before voting begins, the vote will be taken by secret ballot.

Citing (the 2nd para of) EP [Rule 169](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//TEXT+RULES-EP+20130204+RULE-169+DOC+XML+V0//EN), which is actually a bit more complex, for example, its first para says:

> In the case of appointments, voting shall be by secret ballot without prejudice to Rules 13(1), 186(1) and 191(2), second subparagraph.

How often did the EP use this 20% rule [169(2)] to conduct a secret ballot, when one was not otherwise mandated (i.e. excluding appointment votes)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found it extremely difficult to discover data on this. I can state with certainty that a secret ballot was not used between July 16th 2014 and February 25th 2016 (except with respect to appointments & term extensions) thanks to [this dataset [1]](https://www.clarin.si/repository/xmlui/handle/11356/1071) which I was able to analyse.

The only reported use of the secret ballot rule (which has changed to [EP Rule 180a](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/RULES-8-2019-03-05-RULE-180-1_EN.html) in the 2019-2024 parliament) I can find, aside from elections, nominations, and term extensions, is the use during the session on January 31st 2019, where amendments to Parliament's Rules of Procedure were approved during a secret ballot [initiated](https://euobserver.com/institutional/144051) by members from the [EPP group](https://www.eppgroup.eu/) ([full session minutes](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/doceo/document/PV-8-2019-01-31-VOT_EN.pdf)).

I also found [articles](https://www.euractiv.com/section/eu-priorities-2020/news/parliament-to-use-secret-ballot-in-vote-on-eu-budget/) suggesting that the EU's budget for 2014-20 would be voted on in a secret ballot, however, the [results of votes](https://www.europarl.europa.eu/sides/getDoc.do?pubRef=-//EP//NONSGML%20PV%2020131119%20RES-VOT%20DOC%20PDF%20V0//EN&language=EN) for this session show that this did not take place.

I am forced to conclude given lack of evidence to the contrary, that the aforementioned vote on lobbyist transparency is the only previous use of this rule.

- [1] Cherepnalkoski, Darko; Karpf, Andreas; Mozetič, Igor and Grčar, Miha, 2016, 
  *Dataset of European Parliament roll-call votes and Twitter activities MEP 1.0*, Slovenian language resource repository CLARIN.SI, 
  http://hdl.handle.net/11356/1071.